# Pyqt5 image coordinates

Tags: python, pyqt5

I display images with Qlabel.I need image coordinates/pixel coordinates but, I use mouseclickevent its show me only Qlabel coordinates.

for examples my image is 800*753 and my Qlabel geometry is (701,451).I reads coordinates in (701,451) but I need image coordinates in (800*753)

```
def resimac(self):



    filename= QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Resim Yükle', '.', 'Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp *.tif)')

    self.image=QtGui.QImage(filename[0])
    self.pixmap=QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.image)
    self.resim1.setPixmap(self.pixmap)


    self.resim1.mousePressEvent=self.getPixel




def getPixel(self, event):


    x = event.pos().x()
    y = event.pos().y()


    print("X=",x," y= ",y)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're probably setting the [`scaledContents`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#scaledContents-prop) property, but that could also be not true (in case you set a maximum or fixed size for the label).

## The point has to be *mapped* to the pixmap coordinates

When setting a pixmap to a QLabel, Qt automatically resizes the label to its contents.
Well, it does it unless the label has some size constrains: a maximum/fixed size that is smaller than the pixmap, and/or the QLabel has the `scaledContents` property set to True as written above. Note that this also happens if any of its ancestors has some size constraints (for example, the main window has a maximum size, or it's maximized to a screen smaller than the space the window needs).
In any of those cases, the mousePressEvent will obviously give you the coordinates based on the widget, *not* on the pixmap.

First of all, even if it doesn't seem to be that important, you'll have to consider that every widget can have some [contents margins](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contentsMargins): the widget will still receive events that happen *inside the area of those margins*, even if they are outside its actual contents, so you'll have to consider that aspect, and ensure that the event happens within the real geometry of the widget contents (in this case, the pixmap). If that's true, you'll have to translate the event position to that rectangle to get its position according to the pixmap.

Then, if the `scaledContents` property is true, the image will be scaled to the current available size of the label (which also means that its aspect ratio will not be maintained), so you'll need to *scale* the position.
This is just a matter of math: compute the proportion between the image size and the (contents of the) label, then multiply the value using that proportion.

```
    # click on the horizontal center of the widget
    mouseX = 100

    pixmapWidth = 400
    widgetWidth = 200
    xRatio = pixmapWidth / widgetWidth
    # xRatio = 2.0

    pixmapX = mouseX * xRatio
    # the resulting "x" is the horizontal center of the pixmap
    # pixmapX = 200
```

On the other hand, if the contents are not scaled you'll have to consider the QLabel [`alignment`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#alignment-prop) property; it is usually aligned on the left and vertically centered, but that depends on the OS, the style currently in use *and the localization* (consider right-to-left writing languages). This means that if the image is smaller than the available size, there will be some empty space within its margins, and you'll have to be aware of that.

In the following example I'm trying to take care about all of that (I'd have to be honest, I'm not 100% sure, as there *might* be some 1-pixel tolerance due to various reasons, most regarding integer-based coordinates and DPI awareness).
Note that instead of overwriting `mousePressEvent` as you did, I'm using an [event filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter), I'll explain the reason for it afterwards.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        self.getImageButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Select')
        layout.addWidget(self.getImageButton)
        self.getImageButton.clicked.connect(self.resimac)

        self.resim1 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.resim1)
        self.resim1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        # I'm assuming the following...
        self.resim1.setScaledContents(True)
        self.resim1.setFixedSize(701,451)

        # install an event filter to "capture" mouse events (amongst others)
        self.resim1.installEventFilter(self)

    def resimac(self):
        filename, filter = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Resim Yükle', '.', 'Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp *.tif)')
        if not filename:
            return
        self.resim1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(filename))

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        # if the source is our QLabel, it has a valid pixmap, and the event is
        # a left click, proceed in trying to get the event position
        if (source == self.resim1 and source.pixmap() and not source.pixmap().isNull() and 
            event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress and
            event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton):
                self.getClickedPosition(event.pos())
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def getClickedPosition(self, pos):
        # consider the widget contents margins
        contentsRect = QtCore.QRectF(self.resim1.contentsRect())
        if pos not in contentsRect:
            # outside widget margins, ignore!
            return

        # adjust the position to the contents margins
        pos -= contentsRect.topLeft()

        pixmapRect = self.resim1.pixmap().rect()
        if self.resim1.hasScaledContents():
            x = pos.x() * pixmapRect.width() / contentsRect.width()
            y = pos.y() * pixmapRect.height() / contentsRect.height()
            pos = QtCore.QPoint(x, y)
        else:
            align = self.resim1.alignment()
            # for historical reasons, QRect (which is based on integer values),
            # returns right() as (left+width-1) and bottom as (top+height-1),
            # and so their opposite functions set/moveRight and set/moveBottom
            # take that into consideration; using a QRectF can prevent that; see:
            # https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html#right
            # https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html#bottom
            pixmapRect = QtCore.QRectF(pixmapRect)

            # the pixmap is not left aligned, align it correctly
            if align & QtCore.Qt.AlignRight:
                pixmapRect.moveRight(contentsRect.x() + contentsRect.width())
            elif align & QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter:
                pixmapRect.moveLeft(contentsRect.center().x() - pixmapRect.width() / 2)
            # the pixmap is not top aligned (note that the default for QLabel is
            # Qt.AlignVCenter, the vertical center)
            if align & QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom:
                pixmapRect.moveBottom(contentsRect.y() + contentsRect.height())
            elif align & QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter:
                pixmapRect.moveTop(contentsRect.center().y() - pixmapRect.height() / 2)

            if not pos in pixmapRect:
                # outside image margins, ignore!
                return
            # translate coordinates to the image position and convert it back to
            # a QPoint, which is integer based
            pos = (pos - pixmapRect.topLeft()).toPoint()

        print('X={}, Y={}'.format(pos.x(), pos.y()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now. A couple of suggestions.

### Don't overwrite existing child object methods with [other] object's instance attributes

There are various reasons for which this is not a good idea, and, while dealing with Qt, the most important of them is that Qt uses **function caching** for *virtual functions*; this means that as soon as a virtual is called the *first* time, that function will **always** be called in the future. While your approach *could* work in simple cases (especially if the overwriting happens within the parent's `__init__`), it's usually prone to unexpected behavior that's difficult to debug if you're not very careful.

And that's exactly your case: I suppose that `resimac` is not called upon parent instantiation and until after some other event (possibly a clicked button) happens. **But** if the user, for some reason, clicks on the label *before* a new pixmap is loaded, your supposedly overwritten method will **never** get called: at that time, you've not overwritten it yet, so the user clicks the label, Qt calls the QLabel's base class `mousePressEvent` implementation, and then that method will *always* be called from that point on, no matter if you try to overwrite it.

To work around that, you have at least 3 options:

1. use an event filter (as the example above); an event filter is something that "captures" events of a widgets and allows you to observe (and interact) with it; you can also decide to propagate that event to the widget's parent or not (that's mostly the case of key/mouse events: if a widget isn't "interested" about one of those events, it "tells" its parent to care about it); this is the simplest method, but it can become hard to implement and debug for complex cases;
2. subclass the widget and manually add it to your GUI within your code;
3. subclass it and "promote" the widget if you're using Qt's Designer;

### You don't need to use a QImage for a QLabel.

This is not that an issue, it's just a suggestion: QPixmap already uses (*sort of*) `fromImage` within its C++ code when constructing it with a path as an argument, so there's no need for that.